# How to Extract logs between 2 timestamps in Unix

Tags: unix, sed, timestamp, extract, cat

I need to extract the logs between two timestamps from a file in Unix. I basically kind of need those logs to be copied and output in a different file so that I can copy them.
Is there an efficient way to do this? The log format looks like this - The timestamp is in a separate line from the actual logs.

```
Tue 21 Apr 14:00:00 GMT 2020
{"items":[{"cpu.load": "0.94","total.memory": "6039.798 MB","free.memory": "4367.152 MB","used.memory": "1672.646 MB","total.physical.system.memory": "16.656 GB","total.free.physical.system.memory": "3860.197 MB","total.used.physical.system.memory": "12.796 GB","number.of.cpus": "8"}]}
Tue 21 Apr 18:00:00 GMT 2020
{"items":[{"cpu.load": "0.76","total.memory": "6039.798 MB","free.memory": "4352.656 MB","used.memory": "1687.142 MB","total.physical.system.memory": "16.656 GB","total.free.physical.system.memory": "3858.203 MB","total.used.physical.system.memory": "12.798 GB","number.of.cpus": "8"}]}
```

I am doing this but it only prints out the timestamp and not the actual logs

```
cat file.txt | awk -F, '{ if ($1>"Fri 21 Aug 14:00:00 GMT 2020" && $1<"Sat 22 Aug 18:00:00 GMT 2020") print }'
```

Can someone advice.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: @Paolo I want the whole logs between that timestamp and including the timestamp into a new file. 
The file is very huge and contains data from last year as well so I only want the data between a certain timestamp.

Comment: `sed  -n '/Tue 21 Apr 14:00:00 GMT 2020/,/Tue 21 Apr 18:00:00 GMT 2020/p' file.txt`

Comment: So you actually need to compare the timestamps right?

Comment: `Fri 21 Aug` is a terrible format for a timestamp as you can't do less than or greater than comparisons using it to get meaningful results. Can you change whatever's creating these files to use YYYYMMDD (e.g. `20200821`) or similarly compare-able instead?